# How to write content in tabbed panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabbed-view

I am using following code to write data for each pane in tabbed pane.

```
<style>
#variantcontent
{
    margin-left:24px;
    margin-right:24px;
}

#varianttabs ul
{
    font: normal 14px arial, sans, sans-serif;
    -list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    padding-bottom: 26px;
}

#varianttabs ul li 
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    min-width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

#varianttabs ul li.selected 
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}


#varianttabs ul li a 
{
    float: left;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#eee;
    min-width:80px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#varianttabs ul li a.selected
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #909090;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#varianttabs ul li a:hover
{
    color: #fff;   
    background-color:#D0D0D0;
}

#variantcontainer 
{
    background: white;
    border:1px solid gray;
    border-top: none;
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;  
}

iframe
{
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

</style>

<script>

function loadit( element)
{
    var container = document.getElementById('variantcontainer');
    container.src=element.rel;

    var tabs=document.getElementById('varianttabs').getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        if(tabs[i].rel == element.rel) 
            tabs[i].className="selected";
        else
            tabs[i].className="";
    }
}

function startit()
{
    var tabs=document.getElementById('varianttabs').getElementsByTagName("a");
    var container = document.getElementById('variantcontainer');
    container.src = tabs[0].rel;
}

window.onload=startit;


</script>

<div id="variantcontent">
<div id="varianttabs">
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" rel="table.html" onClick="loadit(this)">A</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" rel="variant.html"  onclick="loadit(this)">B</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" rel="fr.html" onClick="loadit(this)">C</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe id="variantcontainer"></iframe>
</div>    
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nLad.png)

I have tables, text and pictures in php page so it will be double work to generate html file and save on server and later import them during onclick event. Is there any way to just write table, text and pictures for each tab instead of importing them by clicking event?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui\jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4\jquery-ui-themes-1.11.4\themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=""tabs>
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1">tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">tab1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="tab-1">
<table>
<tr>
<td>//table data goes here</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
<a href="//your img path goes here"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

hope this is what you are trying to achieve.
you can include your php code inside this code as well like this-

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Naam</td>
                <td>Gemeente</td>
                <td>Datum</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       <?php
          $db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
            if (!db_select) {
                die("Database selection also failed miserably: " . mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("databaseiheko");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT NaamFuif, GemeenteFuif, DatumFuif FROM tblfuiven");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['NaamFuif']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['GemeenteFuif']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo &row['DatumFuif']?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>   
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: save this page as .php and for include the php code within this code like-

Comment: Thanks but where can i find jquery-ui.css for ref and link?

Comment: download it from jquery-ui download @mani and if you were satisfied with the answer then close the question by accepting the answer

Comment: One more thing i want UI in this format.http://i.stack.imgur.com/5nLad.png but in your example it is different layout so how can i contorl in the same form.

Comment: yes you will get that interface or maybe better interface than you are expecting... even i am new learning and i am really astonished to find such great user interface using jquery

Comment: I checked interface is different and i don't know how to change its layout so i am confused. If there is similar interface doing the same, will be better.